# JAVA - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, exception, analytics

```
package parserstruct;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class ParserStruct {

private BufferedInputStream input;


public ParserStruct(String vstup) {
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(vstup.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    input = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
}

private int readChar() throws IOException {
    int c = input.read();
    return c;
}

private int peekChar() throws IOException {
    input.mark(1);
    int r = input.read();
    input.reset();
    return r;
}

private int readSymbol() throws IOException {
    int c = peekChar();
    while (Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
        readChar();
        c = peekChar();
    }
    return readChar();
}

private int peekSymbol() throws IOException {
    int c = peekChar();
    while (Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
        readChar();
        c = peekChar();
    }
    return c;
}


private String getString(int jdiDo) throws IOException, Exception {
    char[] p = new char[jdiDo];
    for (int i = 0; i < jdiDo; i++) {
        p[i] = (char) readSymbol();
    }
    char c = (char) peekChar();

    if (!Character.isSpaceChar(c)) {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect primitive type or String");
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
    return new String(p);
}

public void parse() throws IOException, Exception {
    S();
    System.out.println("YES");
}

private void S() throws IOException, Exception {
    int c = peekSymbol();
    char[] p = new char[8];
    if (c == (int) 't') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            p[i] = (char) readChar();
        }
    } else {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect 't'");
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
    String def = new String(p);
    if (def.equals("typedef ")) {
        T();
    } else {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect 'typedef' you wrote " + def);
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
}


private void T() throws IOException, Exception {
    int c = peekSymbol();
    char[] p = new char[6];
    if (c == (int) 's') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            p[i] = (char) readChar();
        }
    } else {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect 's' after typedef");
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
    String def = new String(p);
    if (!def.equals("struct")) {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect 'struct' you wrote " + def);
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
    c = readSymbol();
    char d = (char) c;
    if (!(c == (int) '{')) {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect '{' after struct");
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
    V();
    c = readSymbol();
    d = (char) c;
    if (!(c == (int) '}')) {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect '}'");
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
    I();
    c = readSymbol();
    d = (char) c;
    if (!(c == (int) ';')) {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect ';'");
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
}

private void V() throws IOException, Exception {
    int c = peekSymbol();
    char d = (char) c;
    if (c == (int) 's') {
        T();
    } else if (c == (int) 'i' || c == (int) 'd' || c == (int) 'S' || c == (int) 'c' || c == (int) 'l') {
        P();
    } else {

        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
    c = peekSymbol();
    d = (char) c;
    if (c != (int) '}') {
        V();
    }

}

private void P() throws IOException, Exception {
    X();
    I();
    int c = readSymbol();
    char d = (char) c;
    if (c != (int) ';') {

        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
}


private void X() throws IOException, Exception {
    int c = peekSymbol();
    char d = (char) c;
    if (c == (int) 'i') {
        String string = getString(3);
        if (!string.equals("int")) {
            //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect int you wrote " + string);
            throw new Exception("NO");
        }
    } else if (c == (int) 'd') {
        String string = getString(5);
        if (!string.equals("double")) {
            //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect int you wrote " + string);
            throw new Exception("NO");
        }
    } else if (c == (int) 'l') {
        String string = getString(4);
        if (!string.equals("long")) {
            //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect int you wrote " + string);
            throw new Exception("NO");
        }
    } else if (c == (int) 'c') {
        String string = getString(4);
        if (!string.equals("char")) {
            //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect int you wrote " + string);
            throw new Exception("NO");
        }
    } else if (c == (int) 'S') {
        String string = getString(6);
        if (!string.equals("String")) {
            //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect int you wrote " + string);
            throw new Exception("NO");
        }
    } else {
        //throw new Exception("parsing error wrong syntax expect primitive type or String");
        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
}

private void I() throws IOException, Exception {
    char c = (char) readSymbol();
    char d = (char) c;
    if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {

        throw new Exception("NO");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParserStruct parser = new ParserStruct(args[0]);
    try {
        parser.parse();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

There is error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at parserstruct.ParserStruct.main(ParserStruct.java:307)
Java Result: 1

307: ParserStruct parser = new ParserStruct(args[0]);

Comment: @Tom means "*not* passing any arguments"

Comment: Im not sure how to fix it :/

Comment: Yes, how @Tom says, if you run the program without any argument, this `exception` is thrown. However, a small readability hint: use `do-while` instead of `while` in your `readSymbol()` method.

Comment: @AndyBrown You're right, I forgot the most important word in that comment :D.

Comment: Could help my how can I start program with arguments? Edit code or w/e. Im not sure if I understand you. Thank you

Comment: That depends on how you're starting your program. So, can you tell us how you do that? And no, you don't have to change your code for that.

Comment: @Ernesto that's another question - please ask a new question about how to start a command line program with arguments. This question has been answered properly, twice, below.

Comment: Thats a problem because im new in java and i got this code and need to finish as soon as possible. Did some changes what i Could, but missing basic knowledge is real. Thats why i asked you..here.

Answer (score 3):

No arguments are being passed while running the program. You can check the `args.length` before passing the `args[0]` to `ParserStruct`.

Comment: It is worth noting that for development purposes in eclipse you can specify launch arguments for debugging through the project properties, under the "Run/Debug Settings" section. This is similarly possible in other IDEs. (Although really this should be done using unit testing which would avoid the need for all of this).

Answer (score 2):

If you run your program without any command line argument, `new ParserStruct(args[0])` will throw that exception, since the `args` array would be empty, so `0` would be an invalid index.